# Error While Trying to Encrypt / Obfuscate my Java Application Jar File

Tags: java, javafx-8, proguard, android-proguard

I am getting the following errors while trying to obfuscate /encrypt my java / javafx application jar files

[enter image description here][1]

Warning: there were 1 classes in incorrectly named files.
         You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
         The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.

```
     If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
     you could try your luck using the '- ignorewarnings' option.
```

Please correct the above warnings first.

Comment: How exactly are you obfuscating them?

Comment: I am obfuscating it using proguard application that is designed to ecrypt the application.